# Why the resulting JSON is being truncated?

Tags: json, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a WebAPI built with .NET Core.

The API returns a list of cities with attractions.
(the one-to-many relationship)

I am using Postman to examine results, but exactly same happens in a browser.

What happens (and its not related to code itself), when I want to get cities without attractions, the returning JSON looks just fine and properly formatted:

[https://localhost:44316/api/cities?includeAttractions=false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdonI.png)

However, when I want to get cities **with** attractions, the returning JSON is being truncated and cannot be formatted:

[https://localhost:44316/api/cities?includeAttractions=true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKZal.png)

Please advice why is it being truncated?

[WebAPI returns proper valid collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBX7n.png)

Models:

```
public class City
{
    public City()
    {
        Attractions = new HashSet<Attraction>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Population { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfAttractions { get { return Attractions.Count(); } }
    public virtual ICollection<Attraction> Attractions { get; set; }
}

public class Attraction
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public virtual City City { get; set; }
}

public class CityInfoContext : DbContext
{
    public CityInfoContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Attraction> Attractions { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Attraction>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.CityId);
            entity.Property(e => e.Description).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(200);
            entity.Property(e => e.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
            entity.HasOne(d => d.City).WithMany(p => p.Attractions).HasForeignKey(d => d.CityId);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<City>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Description).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(200);
            entity.Property(e => e.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: the file might be too large to "beautify", try looking at it in raw

Comment: same thing, its not large at all, 3 cities, each one has 2 attractions, each entity has only 2 string properties less than 20 chars approx (name & description)

Comment: is it your server? can you log out the value you are being sent back on the server before it sends it? check if its valid json

Comment: yes, it's all on my local machine, at the bottom of my post, I added a screenshot from a debugger of WebAPI... everything looks good

Comment: Share us the model for `cities` and `attractions`. What is the implementation for `GetCities`?